# Restore backup with Rsnapshot

Tags: ubuntu, rsnapshot

The system is ubuntu server 12.04.

I am using rSnapshot to back up the system.

I now want to restore everything in the home folder.

I am restoring from an external HDD:
/media/backup/backup_disk_2/server3/hourly.0/localhost/home

What's the restore command?

Comment: My first reaction was to tell you to use `man rsnapshot` but was astonished to find that it doesn't tell you about recovery, so have a +1 instead.

Comment: Yeah I have gone through the docs of rsync and rsnapshot but wasn't able to find any docs on it.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there is a way to do it with rsnapshot.

From my research it seems like people just copy and paste the file back into the directory.

rsync -av /source /destination

Comment: Yes, this answer is correct. Gentoo has it also documented https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/A_simple_backup_scheme_using_rsnapshot#Restoration